# CSR algorithm/size is incorrect.Expected RSA 2048

Tags: ios, braintree

I am trying to integrate apple pay with `braintree`. I have followed up the following instructions to enable apple pay in the brain tree. In the first step, if you click on certificate signing request, it downloads a `braintree_app_pay.certSigningRequest` file which is used in the apple membership.

[image]

When I choose to create payment process certificate, I am getting the following error.[image]

Comment: whoever has clicked on the close button, please let me know the reason!!!!

Comment: This seems like a Braintree issue. What does their tech support say about your issue?

Comment: This question is off-topic because it is about third-party support for a business function, not a coding issue. Please see [Why we're not customer support for \[your favorite company\]?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/255745)

Comment: There are 972 questions on SOF related with braintree.

Comment: I was using Google chrome while uploading the signingRequest, I used Safari as recommended and it worked!

Answer (score 22):

complimenting what @zepp said, you need to specify when creating CRS, and you can that by following the process below

1. Go to Keychain Access
2. Click on Certificate Assistance
3. Click on Request Certificate from Certificate Authority ([click for image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V6WIt.png))
4. Enter all information and click on "Let me specify key pair Information"checkbox, then click on Continue
5. Select KeySize to be 256 and Algorithm to be ECC ([click for image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F7mpf.png))
6. Then click on continue.

Comment: it clearly states on the documentation that you must use the CSR the Braintree provides you.

Comment: But Braintree said `Upload the CSR that you downloaded from Braintree in step 1.
Note: You must use the CSR we provide. Do not create a CSR file yourself.`

Answer (score 10):

<sub>Full disclosure: I work at Braintree. If you have any further questions, feel free to contact [our Support team](https://support.braintreepayments.com).</sub>

Make sure you're selecting the **Apple Pay Certificate** option under **Production** (even if this is for a Sandbox; see the [Braintree Apple Pay configuration docs](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/guides/apple-pay/configuration/ios/v4#apple-pay-certificate-request-and-provisioning) for details) when choosing the type of certificate to add in the Apple Developer portal. Apple Pay CSRs should be generated with ECC, not RSA.

Here's what the CSR prompt screen should look like. Although you'll be uploading the CSR obtained from Braintree instead of generating one, note Apple's specifications for the key:

[image: apple-pay-add-ios-certificate-about-creating-a-csr]

Comment: but it's said 'must use the CSR the Braintree provides you'

Comment: i still get the same error when i tried this, as it wants algorithm RSA (2048), not ECC (256) as we can see in the picture

Answer (score 5):

Please follow below steps[If use Apple Pay with stripe or any other payment gateway]:

1. Double click on CSR (Downloaded from Stripe), [It will open Certificate Assistant]
2. Click on Continue
3. Select 'Request a certificate from an existing CA', and Continue
4. In Certificate Information screen, Enter User Email Address, Common Name, Leave CA Email Address empty, Select 'Saved to disk & checked Let me specify key pair information' [Select your specific location and save]
5. In Key Pair Information screen, select 'ECC' algorithm & select Key size : 256 bits and continue.

Now use this CSR in your payment processing certificate.

Answer (score 4):

This issue is *not* specific to Apple Pay or Braintree - I ran into the same issue when trying to create a CSR for getting a Safari certificate from Apple.

What's important to know is that you need to select the iCloud keychain *before* using the `Request Certificate from Certificate Authority` command. If you don't, another keychain may be active, causing wrong keys to be used.

Answer (score 3):

[From Apple Developer Forum](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/77791)

> Within the Keychain Access drop down menu, select Keychain Access >
>   Certificate Assistant > Request a Certificate from a Certificate
>   Authority.
>
> 1. In the Certificate Information window, enter the following information:
>
>    - In the User Email Address field, enter your email address.
>    - In the Common Name field, create a name for your private key (e.g., John Doe Dev Key).
>    - The CA Email Address field should be left empty.
>    - In the "Request is" group, select the "Saved to disk" option.
>    - Select "Let me specify key pair information".
> 2. Click Continue within Keychain Access and select the file location.
> 3. Set the Key Pair Information to the following:
>
>    - Algorithm: ECC
>    - Key Size: 256 bits Click
> 4. Continue within Keychain Access to complete the CSR generating process.

Answer (score 1):

I don't get it, because it's said `You must use the CSR we provide. Do not create a CSR file yourself` on `braintree` website.

And with this CSR file, it's always failed on apple's upload page.

Edit:
I finally upload success with follow steps of @anjali-jariwala 's answer.
Just in last step, I choose `RSA` & `2048` as alert requirement.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

For me I accidentally chose `Yes` when asked `Will payments associated with this Merchant ID be processed exclusively in China?`

Choosing `No` solved the issue for me

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error. The mistake on my part was choosing the wrong type of certificate while creating it in the Apple developer portal. I used 'Apple Pay Merchant Identity Certificate', but I needed to use 'Apple Pay Payment Processing Certificate', which solved the issue.